# Android libgdx big screen resolution

Tags: android, libgdx

How can I support (make an algorithm) for libgdx for supporting multiple screen resolution? I made my app work on HTC Tattoo using if statments with parameters like:

```
if (Gdx.input.getX()==40) {
```

What is a good algorithm for making this work on bigger screens?
I tried this but without any result:

```
publis static int translatex() {
     float p = (float)Gdx.graphics.getHeight()*340;
     return (int) p*Gdx.input.getX();
}
```

340 is the base x (the x resolution on my phone) used by me on the HTC Tattoo.
So.....how can I make a function for supporting big screens with absolute values. I don`t want to change the if-statements.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's pretty easy. You basically build your entire program for your native resolution, but in everything dealing with positioning and texture sizing have something like this:

```
private void resize()
{
    float x = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float y = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    float changeX = x / assumeX; //being your screen size that you're developing with
    float changeY = y / assumeY;

    position = new Vector2(position.x * changeX, position.y * changeY);
    width = startWidth * changeX;
    height = startHeight * changeY;
    bounds = new Vector2 (position.x, (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - position.y) - height);

}
```

Basically what you're doing is taking every object generated and running it through something that increases/decreases depending on the change in the x/y values in your resolution. The further it is from the native, the bigger it will be. When checking of something is somewhere or putting something somewhere, always code it as your desired resolution but run it through a resize function before displaying it or letting it interact with the rest of your program.

Comment: For an example of this implemented, refer to my StringBuild tutorial on the libgdx wiki.

Comment: What is startWidth? And resize function have 2 parameters int width, int height, that startWidth is width?

Comment: start width/height will be the size of your texture natively before resizing. the new width and height are the increases in respect to the changeX and changeY. Bounds is merely a vector2 holding the opposite corner's position so you can easily know the bounds of the object.

Call object to be created --> get all initial values such as position, width, height -> Convert them with the resize() function --> draw the texture onto screen. We keep startHeight and height separate in a case of using textureRegions, when you need to know the basic size of the texture so that you can stretch it properly

Comment: Can you please put some code? I`m not a english native speaker.

Comment: I used this method to resize my image and it worked great! Thank you! Though I came across one problem. My images get resized, but when I call `setRotation()` later on, the image is rotated around it's old center point. Any ideas?

Comment: For a 2d game, I have found it way easier to just set the zoom on the OrthographicCamera. I usually target 1080p and then zoom in/out as needed.

Comment: @Remm The link you provided is dead now. I am unable to find a replacement. Any chance you know where this link is now?

Comment: A shame, it looks like they changed their wiki and decided not to bring it over. However my example is 2 years old, so I'm not sure if it is deprecated. Their wiki is https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Introduction - sorry I can't be of more help, I stopped using libGDX quite a while ago.

Answer (score 3):

See a more elegant solution at http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=25685.0 (also see Nate's comment to that solution).

Also, if you use `scene2d`, note that currently (libgdx 0.9.6) `stage.setViewport` method should have this functionality, but it doesn't really behave as one would expect.

**Update:** setViewPort was fixed, so this works just as expected.