# Button not showing on android device

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a wierd issue with a button not showing on the android device. Let me present you with the code constructing the button:

```
private void setUpRetry() {
        texture = new TextureAtlas("ui/button.pack");
        skin = new Skin(texture);

        BitmapFont white = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("font/white.fnt"), false);

        table = new Table(skin);
        table.setBounds(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

        TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
        textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("red_button01");
        textButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("red_button02");
        textButtonStyle.pressedOffsetX = 1;
        textButtonStyle.pressedOffsetY = -1;
        textButtonStyle.font = white;

        buttonRetry = new TextButton("Retry", textButtonStyle);
        buttonRetry.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            public void clicked(InputEvent evet, float x, float y) {
                ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new GameScreen());
            }
        });

        buttonRetry.pad(40, 150, 40, 150);
        buttonRetry.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - buttonRetry.getWidth() / 2,
 Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - buttonRetry.getHeight()); // this don't
        buttonRetry.setPosition(305, 430); // this line works

        this.addActor(buttonRetry);

    }
```

I want to make sure for future reference that I will not get problems with a button in the middle of the screen. Therefor I'd like to set the button not my coordinates but by the native width and height of the app. Yet, I can't seem to get it done.
The problem is setting the height. If I replace that with, say, 400 - the button shows!

I am debugging on a Samsung Galaxy S5 if that helps.

If I/we connot resolve the issue, is it fine to set the coordinate of the button by numbers and not native width and so on?

Picture of the desktop version of both lines commented out:
[image]

As you can see, the desktop has them at the same spot.

---

EDIT:

I have resorted to use of the method that works but will leave the question open as it has not been resolved.

Comment: Is layout finished before calling buttonRetry.setPosition() ?

Comment: Yeah, the code works aswell. When i use `buttonRetry.setPosition(305, 430);` the button is placed perfectly, id just like to use the method above this line in my code.

Comment: In layout, 1. (width and height are 0) -> 2.(width and height are set) I think. (2.) is finished?

Comment: Im not quite sure what you ask.
The pictures?

Answer (score 0):

---

This answer may contain some old info.

In some environment, display resolution may cause positioning problem.
To solve the problem, scale positions.

In sample/test code below (Game.java)

`onWindowResize()` : not scaled

`onWindowResize_Scaled()` : scaled

(Old wiki)
https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/DisplayResolution

(Faking the desktop DPI)
http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=949

[Android libgdx big screen resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988308/android-libgdx-big-screen-resolution)

---

// MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;

public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
        initialize((ApplicationListener) new Game());
    }
}
```

---

// Game.java

```
import android.util.Log;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Application.ApplicationType;
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton.TextButtonStyle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ClickListener;

public class Game implements ApplicationListener
{
    private int windowWidth;
    private int windowHeight;
    private float ratioX = 1f;
    private float ratioY = 1f;
    private TextureAtlas texture;
    private Skin skin;
    private Table table;
    private TextButton buttonRetry;

    @Override
    public void create()
    {
        setUpRetry();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void render()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int arg0, int arg1)
    {
        if ((0 == arg0) || (0 == arg1))
        {
            // may not occur
            return;
        }
        this.windowWidth = arg0; // If display resolution is hard coded, this may not match maGdx.graphics.getWidth()
        this.windowHeight = arg1;
        Log.d("resize", "arg:(" + windowWidth + ", " + windowHeight + ")"); // just for check
        // setUpRetry();
        // onWindowResize();
        onWindowResize_Scaled(); // In dpi (or fixed resolution) problem, use this.
    }

    @Override
    public void resume()
    {
    }

    private void onWindowResize()
    {
        //
        // Fixed ratio
        // Use (arg0, arg1) in resize() as (windowWidth, windowHeight)
        //
        if ((0 == windowWidth) || (0 == windowHeight))
        {
            // called before resize()
            return;
        }
        // ratioX = 1f;
        // ratioY = 1f;
        if (null != table)
        {
            table.setBounds(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
        }
        if (null != buttonRetry)
        {
            buttonRetry.pad(40, 150, 40, 150); // This may be effected by dpi, but it's hard coded. Just adjust (or use ratioX and ratioY to scale).
            {
                // If position has minus value (may be called before resize()), view will be displayed at unwanted position.
                float posX = (windowWidth - buttonRetry.getWidth()) / 2;
                float posY = (windowHeight - buttonRetry.getHeight());
                buttonRetry.setPosition(posX, posY);
            }
            // buttonRetry.setPosition(305, 430); // this line works
            Log.d("onWindowResize", "pos:(" + buttonRetry.getX() + ", " + buttonRetry.getY() + ")"); // for check
        }
    }

    private void onWindowResize_Scaled()
    {
        //
        // Scaled
        // Use (getWidth() * ratioX) and (getHeight() *ratioY) for each view
        //
        // * This part may contain some old information (as https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/ says the wiki is outdated) *
        // If dpi causes unwanted behavior (mentioned in http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=949)
        // use ratioX and ratioY as Gdx size (getWidth() or getHeight()) to displayed size ratio.
        // (All window/views are scaled same, so this is not needed I think.)
        //
        // May be effected by hard coded display resolution (https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/DisplayResolution) or
        // View port (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports)
        //
        // (from http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=949)
        int windowWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        int windowHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        if (Gdx.app.getType() == ApplicationType.Android)
        {
            ratioX = Gdx.graphics.getPpiX() / 160;
            ratioY = Gdx.graphics.getPpiY() / 160;
            // ratioX = 160 / Gdx.graphics.getPpiX();
            // ratioY = 160 / Gdx.graphics.getPpiY();
            Log.d("onWindowResize", "Gdx window Size:(" + windowWidth + ", " + windowHeight + ")"); // just for check
            Log.d("onWindowResize", "Scaled window Size:(" + windowWidth * ratioX + ", " + windowHeight * ratioY + ")"); // just for check
            Log.d("onWindowResize", "ratio:(" + ratioX + ", " + ratioY + ")"); // just for check
        }
        else
        {
            // hard coded resolution (480 x 320) for desktop (if not changed from default)
            // https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/DisplayResolution
            int w;
            int h;
            boolean isLandscape = windowWidth > windowHeight;
            if (isLandscape)
            {
                w = 480;
                h = 320;
            }
            else
            {
                w = 320;
                h = 480;
            }
            ratioX = windowWidth / w;
            ratioY = windowHeight / h;
            // ratioX = w / windowWidth;
            // ratioY = h / windowHeight;
            Log.d("onWindowResize", "Gdx window Size:(" + windowWidth + ", " + windowHeight + ")"); // just for check
            Log.d("onWindowResize", "Scaled window Size:(" + windowWidth * ratioX + ", " + windowHeight * ratioY + ")"); // just for check
            Log.d("onWindowResize", "ratio:(" + ratioX + ", " + ratioY + ")"); // just for check
        }
        if (null != table)
        {
            table.setBounds(0, 0, windowWidth * ratioX, windowHeight * ratioY);
        }
        if (null != buttonRetry)
        {
            buttonRetry.pad(40, 150, 40, 150); // This may be effected by dpi, but it's hard coded. Just adjust (or use ratioX and ratioY to scale).
            {
                // If position has minus value (may be called before resize()), view will be displayed at unwanted position.
                float posX = (windowWidth - buttonRetry.getWidth()) / 2 * ratioX;
                float posY = (windowHeight - buttonRetry.getHeight()) * ratioY;
                buttonRetry.setPosition(posX, posY);
            }
            // buttonRetry.setPosition(305, 430); // this line works
            Log.d("onWindowResize", "pos:(" + buttonRetry.getX() + ", " + buttonRetry.getY() + ")"); // for check
        }
    }

    private void setUpRetry()
    {
        // if ((0 == windowWidth) || (0 == windowHeight))
        // {
        // // called before resize()
        // // Show error message or do some recovery or silently return
        // return;
        // }
        texture = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("ui/button.pack"));
        skin = new Skin(texture);
        BitmapFont white = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("font/white.fnt"), false);
        table = new Table(skin);
        // table.setBounds(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
        TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
        textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("red_button01");
        textButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("red_button02");
        textButtonStyle.pressedOffsetX = 1;
        textButtonStyle.pressedOffsetY = -1;
        textButtonStyle.font = white;
        buttonRetry = new TextButton("Retry", textButtonStyle);
        buttonRetry.addListener(new ClickListener()
        {
            public void clicked(InputEvent evet, float x, float y)
            {
                Game game = (Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener();
                if ((0 == game.windowWidth) || (0 == game.windowHeight))
                {
                    // called before resize()
                    // Show error message or do some recovery or silently return
                    return;
                }
                game.setScreen(new GameScreen());
            }
        });
        // buttonRetry.pad(40, 150, 40, 150);
        // buttonRetry.setPosition((windowWidth - buttonRetry.getWidth()) / 2, windowHeight - buttonRetry.getHeight());
        // // buttonRetry.setPosition(305, 430); // this line works
        // Log.d("setUpRetry", "pos:(" + buttonRetry.getX() + ", " + buttonRetry.getY() + ")"); // for check
        this.addActor(buttonRetry); // If this needs position or size of buttonRetry, (remove old actor and) call in onWindowResize
    }

    private void setScreen(GameScreen gameScreen)
    {
    }

    private void addActor(TextButton button)
    {
    }
}

class GameScreen
{
}
```

Comment: The code works fine for `button.getHeight()` I've just tried to print the value of `Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - button.getHeight()` which returns 1030f. So my issue is that the "native" width is higher than the 480 that the picture is, and what is displayed.

Comment: It seems dpi problem.

Comment: Yeah, when doing as you said, I print a value of 431 - nearly what i set and what works if i just type `430` but still no button.

Comment: I am sorry, but I'm too noobish to be able to implement that piece of code. See my edit (in a min) of what i did.